# What is the relationship between $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$ and $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T^2))$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T$ is an endomorphism: $T:V\to V$. What is the relationship, betweeen:

$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$ and $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T^2))$

I feel that, $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))=\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T^2))$ since the map keeps the same dimensions as was in the domain, therefore applied twice would keep the same dimension.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you find a matrix that squares to zero but isn't zero? Are the dimensions the same in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\operatorname{im}T^2\subset \operatorname{im}T$$
in fact if $y\in \operatorname{im}T^2$ then there's $x\in V$ such that
$$y=T^2x=T(Tx)\in \operatorname{im}T$$
Now consider the restriction of $T$ on $\operatorname{im}T$
$$T_{|\operatorname{im}T}\colon \operatorname{im}T\to \operatorname{im}T^2$$
then we see by the rank-nullity theorem that 
$$\operatorname{im}T^2=\operatorname{im}T\iff \ker T_{|\operatorname{im}T}=\{0\}\iff \ker T\cap \operatorname{im}T=\{0\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear map represented by the following matrix:

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}  $

What is the dimension of A (and $A^2$)?

Comment: dim(A)=1, dim(A^2)=0? Therefore not the same.

Comment: Yes, that's why the statement does not hold. (In general)

Comment: Is that still the case for when T:V↦V is an endomorphism? I would think this example of A would not exist in a map from V to V.

Comment: The map above is an endomorphism from R^3 to R^3

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dansmith If by "from $V$ to $V$" you mean a surjective map from $V$ to $V$, then you're correct.

Comment: @Jack M The Endomorphism implies surjectivity. Correct as in they are equal?

Comment: @Dansmith This is wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism But automorphism would imply surjectivity, maybe you mixed them up?

Answer (score 1):

The map $T_1:(x,y) \mapsto (x,0)$ and $T_2(x,y) \mapsto (0,x)$ show that the extremes of $T^2 = T$ and $T^2= 0$ can be achieved. Kernel dimension is a bit easier to see: In general we should have that $\dim \ker T \leq \dim \ker T^2 \leq 2\dim\ker T$. And I think one can cook up an example for any case allowed there. A similar statement for images can be derived from Rank-Nullity.

Comment: Would it be: dim(V)-dim(Im(T))≤dim(V)-dim(Im(T^2)), dim(Im(T^2))≤dim(Im(T))

Comment: Also where do yo get that Kernel identity from?

Answer (score 1):

If $T:V\to V$ is an automorphism (a *bijective* linear map), then we have $T(V)=T^n(V)$ for all $n\geq0$. Otherwise the sequence $(T^n(V))_n$ decreases with respect to inclusion (each subspace is included in the previous one).